# Not able to deploy a new project with functions - "reached maximum number of projects attached to this billing account"

Tags: firebase

I was trying to deploy a new project with functions and eventually got message that says I need to upgrade to blaze since functions deployment now require a paid service (click to enlarge the below image).

[image]

But after trying to upgrade I've got the following message:

[image]

Checking my billing account I could see that I had 9 projects linked to my billing account when it didn't allow me to add the 10th project.

After removing 4 unused projects and getting the number of blaze projects down to 5, it still didn't allow me to add the project, showing the same error above.

My request to increase my billing quota using [this form](https://support.google.com/code/contact/billing_quota_increase) was rejected.

Now I ended up with a firebase account where I can't deploy new projects. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to your GCP billing page at https://console.cloud.google.com/billing
2. Select an organization - in case you have more than one
3. Click on CREATE ACCOUNT button to create a new billing account
4. Go to firebase console and try to upgrade your plan to Blaze again. This time you should select your newly created billing account.

I guess a single billing account can hold max of 5 projects on Blaze.

When managing billing accounts, I would suggest organizing yourself by projects or environments. Personally, I have a specific billing accounts for DEVELOPMENT and PRODUCTIONS so that I can keep track of cost separately. Also set proper budget threshold alerts for each billing account for no surprises at the end of the month.

Comment: yes, this is what I ended up doing as well. That looks clunky thought - is this how it's supposed to be set up? I don't really understand the reason for firebase/google behind pushing us into creating multiple billing accounts just to overcome a limit that doesn't make much sense.